# Given a permutation of n integers, how fast can a corresponding Standard Young's Tableau be created?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, combinatorics, word-combinatorics

The Schensted insertion algorithm has an $O(n^2)$ running time, for constructing such a standard Young's Tableaux.

But, since every permutation has a unique Young's tableau, there seems no reason as to why it cannot be done in $O(n \log n)$ time, which is the optimal time to identify a permutation.

Are there any known non-trivial $\textbf{lower bounds or upper bounds}$ for this?

Any assistance/guidance towards any of the questions is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Sample input permutation

5,7,2,3,4,1,6

Output Young's Tableaux

1,3,4,6
2,7
5

Comment: I suggest editing the question to incorporate that information, so the question stands on its own.  We want questions to be self-contained, so people don't need to read the comments to understand what you are asking.  Also, it sounds like the correspondence is to *pairs* of Young tableaux, not to a single tableux; if that is correct, please make the corresponding change as well.  Thank you!

Comment: @D.W:- No Sir, i do not need pair of Young tableaux, just a single tableaux.
For eg. the tableaux on  page 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson%E2%80%93Schensted_correspondence

Corresponds to the permutation
8,3,1,5,2,4,7

Comment: I think you need to specify the desired output more precisely.  When you say that every permutation corresponds to a unique Young's tableaux, what correspondence do you have in mind?  The correspondence listed on Wikipedia is between a permutation and a *pair* of standard Young's tableaux (*not* between a permutation and a single Young's tableaux).  Perhaps given a permutation, you want the first of the pair of tableaux that correspond to it?

Comment: @D.W. :- I have made the changes, and given an example in the description. I hope this clarifies everything.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that no faster algorithm is known, at least if you are interested in computing both tableaux. Dan Romik shows in his paper [The Number of Steps in the Robinson-Schensted Algorithm](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Eromik/data/uploads/papers/schensted.pdf) that on almost all permutations, the computational complexity is actually only $\Theta(n^{3/2} \log n)$. Duzhin, Kuzmin and Vasilliev show in their work [RSK bumping trees and a fast RSK algorithm](https://pca-pdmi.ru/2019/files/39/PCA2019.pdf) how to speed up the algorithm in practice by a significant constant factor. This is all I could find on the topic.

Comment: I would hug you, if you were besides me right now. How did you know all this? You have no idea how much I am grateful to you.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I just googled some keywords.